# Java: Selenium Webdriver fails to sendKeys() when input auto-formats

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, sendkeys

I want to fill a input field on a website with selenium webdriver. the input field looks like this:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9,.]*" class="checkThousandSeparator hideNumberSpin" name="metal" tabindex="1" id="metal" value="0" onblur="updateVariables();" onkeyup="checkRessourceByType('metal'); updateVariables();" onkeypress="return submitOnEnter(event);">
```

So I never had a problem at filling an input field before. but this one auto-formats the input, so if you enter 24424 it automatically makes 24.424 out of it.

If I use the Webdriver now to enter a value, I can enter it (for example 4200) and the input field makes 4.200 out of it. but when I submit the form which belongs to the input field, it changes the value to 0.
the crazy thing is if I enter a value below 1000 and the input field doesn't need to format it, I can submit the right number. Anyone knows why?

what I already tried:

- make sleep
- make a slower input with sendKeys (so only 1 char then 300 milliseconds wait)

But both didn't help. here is my code -

```
//doesn't work, form will submit a "0"
int met = 4200;
driver.findElement(By.id("metal")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(met));

//works, form submits the right value
int met = 200;
driver.findElement(By.id("metal")).sendKeys(Integer.toString(met));
```

There is no error or anything

**Edit**: I forgot to say: The form only fails to submit the right value, if I enter the value with selenium Webdriver. if I enter the
value manually, the form always submits the right value, even if it's > 1000.

**Edit2 Solution**: Ok. Instead of using the sendKeys()-Method, it is required to set the value via JavaScriptExecuter.

```
//This works:
int met = 550000;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('metal').setAttribute('value', '"+met+"')");
```

Comment: Ensure the code works with a simple HTML form without Javascript handlers messing with with input. Test your automation against such a simplified form.

Comment: the code does work. like i said: the problem is not the code, its the auto-formation of the input field. why else it works correctly when entering a value < 1000? also this is a bigger project where i fill in forms all the time. it ALWAYS worked yet with exactly this code if there was no javascript handler messing with the input

Comment: How long does it take to load the page? Do you wait long enough before entering values? I can imagine that the page does some initialization. If you do not wait long enough before entering values, the initial state might get reset _after_ you've typed keys. Though I think this is unlikely since one digit more seems to work just fine. Maybe you can _quickly_ enter three digits manually and reproduce it for manual input, though?

Comment: Well, like I said in my answer, you've to debug the handlers yourself or provide us with a [bare minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (maybe you can extract the relevant Javascript code into a minimum test page and narrow the cause down from there?).

Comment: Please add all other things you've _initially_ tried to your question. Use the "edit" link below you post.

Comment: ok, thank you for your efforts. the idea to edit the value directly via JavaScriptExecuter worked! I edited the Mainpost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can remove the pattern attribute and the class attribute using selenium. Then you can try to enter the value you want.

Try out it

Comment: thank you, i will try it out when i am home and tell if it works

Comment: thank you, editing the value with javascript worked indeed!

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe sounds like a bug to me. Assuming that it does not happen when you type manually it might be caused by the fact that Selenium "presses" the keys very quickly.

Waiting a little after each key press might help:

```
String[] digits = "200".split("");
for (String digit : digits) {
    inputElement.sendKeys(digit);
    Thread.sleep(250);
}
```

Without knowing the implementation of these handlers it's not possible to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
int met = 4200;
driver.findElement(By.id("metal")).sendKeys("" + met);
```

and also this,

```
String met = "4200";
driver.findElement(By.id("metal")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(met));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("metal")).sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD4, Keys.NUMPAD2, Keys.NUMPAD0, Keys.NUMPAD0);
```

and also using `JavaScript`,

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('metal').value='4200';");
```

Give it a try.

Comment: You just provide different ways of converting the number to a string (shall make absolutely no difference) or entering the same char sequence (makes probably no difference). Assuming entering the value via Javascript works _in this case_, it could probably cause other problems since the required event handlers are not triggered.

Comment: @try-catch-finally Yes, because he needs to enter that number. So he should try all the possible methods. Sometimes the first method works with these situations and Javascript also should work.